# Bootstrap 5.1.3 Nav-Bar (button) collapse button not functioning properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Once I click on the collapsed nav-bar button it expands and shows the nav-bar contents but after again clicking on the button it does not collapse again. Below is the html code.

```
*<!-- CSS Stylesheet -->*
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  *<!-- Bootstap Scripts -->*
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #95D1CC;">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Simon Game</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="CSS-My Site/about_index.html">About Developer</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Instructions/instructions_index.html">Instructions</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: As a sideline.... You are calling `Bootstrap 5 Bundle`, `Bootstrap 5 Core` and `Popper`. You don't need all of these. Bootstrap Bundle is the same as Bootstrap Core except that Popper is included with it. So you are calling both Bootstrap and Popper twice in the code above.

Comment: Thank for this information. After removing bootstrap and popper and by calling only bundle, the nav-bar button is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are including it all twice. It won't work this way.

You should EITHER include `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` OR (`popper.min.js` + `bootstrap.min.js`).

I had the same problem, and in my case I was inadvertedly doing this, which is wrong and causes the same problem:

```
import "bootstrap"
import "bootstrap/js/src/collapse"; // remove, otherwise it will not work
```